# A problem of diagram chasing

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Consider the following diagram of functions between sets:

[image]

I know that the $4$ inner triangles (i.e. $\{X,X',Z\}$,$\{X',Y',Z\}$...) are all commutative diagrams  and moreover that $f_1$ and $f_3$ are bijective functions.

Can I conclude that the outer square $\{X,X',Y',Y\}$ is a commutative diagram?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can't. Take for example $X=X'=Z=\{a\}$, $Y=Y'=\{a,b\}$, $f_1,f_3,a,b$ the identity maps. Then set $f_2\colon a\mapsto a$ and $f_4\colon a\mapsto b$. Then every triangle commute but the big square doesn't.

More generally, you can take $X=X'$, $Y=Y'$, $f_1,f_3$ the identity maps. Then you pick two different maps $f_2,f_4\colon X\to Y$ and you set $Z$ as the equalizer of those maps and $X\to Z$ the map that you get composing $f_2$ with the equalizer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $X=X=Y=Y'=\left\{x,y\right\}$, $Z=\left\{x\right\}$, $f_1=f_3=\operatorname{id}_{\left\{x,y \right\}}$, $a,b,c,d$ and $f_4$ the constant functions $z\mapsto x$ and $f_2$ the constant function $z\mapsto y$.